# Meta Stack Exchange in relationship with the site Meta of Mathematics Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, meta, stackexchange

I would like to know what is the relationship of the site Meta Stack Exhange and the site Meta of Mathematics Stack Exchange.

I am not member of the community Meta Stack Exchange, I don't know if this is related to the site Meta of Mathematics Stack Exchange. In particular I would like to know if I can join to this community and ask questions in a similar way that I do in this Meta Stack Exchange. I don't know what concerns are adressed on the site Meta Stack Exchange. For example I don't know if it is possible to do a cross-posted on this site, or edit and add comments on the site Meta Stack Exchange question in a similar way that I do here on this Meta Mathematics Stack Exchange.

> **Question.** What is the relationship of Meta Stack Exchange and the Meta site of this Mathematics Stack Exchange? I would like to know if I can do questions related to some specific Stack Exchange site, for example this Mathematics Stack Exchange, in the site Meta Stack Exchange. **Many thanks.**

I hope that I have not misunderstood the situation of possible relationship of both sites, I want to know this information (see also the previous second paragraph) just from an informative point of view. Thus if you can to add a concise overview about my doubts it is good. I don't know what is the scope/goal of site Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: If the situation of possible relationship is a misunderstood of mine or this post isn't suitable, please add a comment with the purpose to delete this post.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jfU0.png :-)

Comment: Many thanks, now I'm glad @uhoh

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The site Meta Stack Exchange is a site in its own right. You can ask questions about the Stack Exchange Network there, and questions that concern all or at least several sites in the Stack Exchange Network.

If the question is *only* about Mathematics Stack Exchange, or a single site more generally,  then it is better to ask it here, or on the relevant per-site meta.

The site Meta Stack Exchange is slightly different to a per-site meta site in that one does get points there. But other than that it works in much the same was as this meta site here.

If you want to join it, you just go there and click "sign up." You account there will usually be linked to this one.

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent answer and advice (I mean the second paragraph). If I need more additional information in future weeks/months I should add a comment here, after I try ask my question on this Meta of Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: I am glad you found my answer useful. To get a more detailed idea you could watch what questions get asked on [meta.se].

Comment: Today I joint to Meta Stack Exchange as user801682 , I'm considering ask about a serious concern with an user of Mathematics Stack Exchange. I've contacted with the site Stack Exchange (Help Center > Contact), adding some of the flags for which I'm owner. If these persons can provide a response I should to accept their words. On the other hand I am considering don't ask my question on this Meta Mathematics Stack Exchange and ask directly on Meta Stack Exchange, and other responses in terms of legitimate defense. Many thanks, isn't required a reply for this comment.